# Mongoose reference overwritten

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am in a bit of a pickle. Whenever I create a new resume as a logged in user it doesn't add the resume id as an array. I.e, ["20293", "2932392", "32903239"]

Instead, it overwrites the current resume id in the users schema. Here is the code

UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _vId: {
        type: String,
        default: id.generate()
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    accountType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Alphaneer', 'Administrator', 'Support', 'PRO'],
        default: 'Alphaneer'
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        default: "No bio provided."
    },
    // TODO: Hash the password before inserting as a document :)
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: String,
        default: moment(new Date()).format("MMM DD, YYYY") // "Sun, 3PM 17"
    },
    resume: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Resume" } ]
});
```

---

Where I post my resume

```
 // POST /dashboard/resume/create
router.post('/resume/create', (req, res, next) => {
  Resume.create(req.body, (err, resume) => {
    if (err) {
      var err = new Error("Error:" + err);
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      req.user = jwtDecode.decode(req.session.tokenID, 'secret');
      //I am assuming that you have saved your resume and getting the saved object in `resume`, now update the logged in user in req.user
      var user = req.user.sessionId;
      var updateData = {
        resume: resume._id
      }
      //save the updated user
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, updateData, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(user);
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

[gif of submitting new resumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqceD.gif)

UPDATE:

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2pUq.png)

UPDATED CODE:

```
// POST /dashboard/resume/create
router.post('/resume/create', (req, res, next) => {
  Resume.create(req.body, (err, resume) => {
    if (err) {
      var err = new Error("Error:" + err);
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      req.user = jwtDecode.decode(req.session.tokenID, 'secret');
      //I am assuming that you have saved your resume and getting the saved object in `resume`, now update the logged in user in req.user
      var user = req.user.sessionId;
      var updateData = {
        resume: resume._id
      }
      //save the updated user
      User.findById(user, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          user.resume.push(resume.id)
          user.save(function(user) {
            return res.json(user);
          });
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: It seems you want to rather push a new `Resume` ID instead updating the entire `User` model. In this case, I think it is best to find the `User` as you are doing, and then say `user.resume.push(resume.id)` and then save the `User` model.

Comment: Oh okay, perhaps I will give that a shot.

Comment: I tried my best to follow your suggestion and I think I got it but it comes up with an error regarding resumes not being an array? I am pretty sure I set the resume to be an array.

Comment: ObjectId('585e64e82eb02d0a82c4873a') is my current signed in account.

Comment: I suspect you may have needed to call toJSON() on the Mongoose model. I have posted my answer, see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
var user = req.user.sessionId;
  var updateData = {
    resume: resume._id
  }
  //save the updated user
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, updateData, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(user);
    }
  });
```

The `resume` field is an array and you are manipulating it as a string field. The method `findOneAndUpdate` do two things:

1. Find the document by it's id
2. Update it with the new data

The second argument is the new data to set. So, the second step is translated to:

```
User.upate({ _id: user }, { resume: resume._id });
```

Can you see what's wrong? `resume` **must** store an array of resume's id and your are setting a id as value. Obviously this will throw an MongooseError.

Your second shot is correct but has a typo error:

```
User.findById(user, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      user.resume.push(resume.id)
      user.save(function(user) {
        return res.json(user);
      });
    }
  });
```

You must add the `_id` field since this is the ObjectID of the new created document (resume). So, you need to do `user.resume.push(resume._id)` instead.

**Update**

According with your last comment, you want to populate your User model, that is, through association id's retrieve all model data. In this case, is recommended that the resumes array change like this:

```
...
resumes: [
  {
     resume: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Resume'
     }
   }
 ]
```

To populate the User document with all Resume data you just need to reference the `resume` key in `resumes` field array.

```
User.findById(user, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: err.message });
    }
    user.resume.push(resume.id)
    user.save(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: err.message });
      }
      // save was fine, finally return the user document populated
      User.findById(user).populate('resumes.resume').exec(function(err, u) {
        return res.json(u);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The `populate` method accepts a string with the fields that we want fill with it model data. In your case is an only field (`resume`). After run the query, you will get something like this:

```
{
  _id: a939v0240mf0205jf48ut84sdfdjg4,
  ...,
  resumes: [
    resume: {
      _id: f940tndfq4ut84jofgh03ut85dg9454g,
      title: 'Some title'
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: So I should be using findOneAndUpdate instead?

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand right away I am not a huge pro at coding lol

Comment: Don't worry. Your first code is wrong, the second is fine but you just need to replace `user.resume.push(resume.id)` by `user.resume.push(resume._id)`. Try it and comment. In MongoDB, the ObjectID's are store on `_id` field.

Comment: ```"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ verify: [Function: verify] }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""``` I'm clueless lol. I've been working on this for a while now.

Comment: That's a common error when using findById. You must be sure that req.user.sessionId is a **valid ObjectId**.

Comment: So like ObjectId("blah")? Cause it's definitely not. Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: No. When I say "a valid ObjectId" I mean that the value of `req.user.sessionId` is an ObjectId string, for example: am494v39t4nv84....

Comment: The ObjectId's follow a well defined pattern, so, MongoDB will recognize when you pass a valid ObjectId or an invalid one.

Comment: Okay, so I noticed I never defined a user so I did that now the entire thing just shows null lol

Comment: Great, Merry Christmas too!

Comment: Actually sorry to bother but how would I access that information cause it would only show up as an id instead of the actual titles and whatnot.

Answer (score -1):

Just to follow up on my comment regarding how I suggest you solve the issue:

```
router.post('/resume/create', (req, res, next) => {
  Resume.create(req.body, (err, resume) => {
    if (err) {
      var err = new Error("Error:" + err);
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      req.user = jwtDecode.decode(req.session.tokenID, 'secret');

    //Here, instead of creating a new key entry for resume, you rather push new resume-id into the resume property of the "found user".      
      //find, update and save the user
      User.findOne({_id: req.user.sessionId}, function (err, userToUpdate) {
         userToUpdate.toJSON().resume.push(resume.id);
         userToUpdate.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
      });
    });

    }
  })
});
```

I left the rest of your code (saving new resume) untouched - I assume that part works. Give this a try and let me know if you encounter some problems.

Comment: Your method unfortunately doesn't even show a resume id at all.

Comment: That is odd - I think the `resume_.id` might be the issue - I assumed that will be the name of the ID key in mongoose models - it should be `resume.id` then instead. Updated the answer as necessary.